# Unit Test AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-node

I have the below AngularJS service class, how can I write Jasmine unit test class for that service?

```
quoteApp.service('TravelInfoService', function() {
    this.travelAreaTest = function() {
        return 'TESTVAL';
    };
    this.travelAreaDiasbled = function(currentTripType) {
        if (currentTripType.substring(0, 4) == 'SING') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
});
```

unit test class

```
describe('sample test', function() {

var travelInfoService = null;

  beforeEach(module('quoteApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(TravelInfoService) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  travelInfoService = TravelInfoService;

}));


it('should not be false', function() {
  expect(travelInfoService.travelAreaTest()).toEqual(false);
});

});
```

This unit-test class is not working so need help to correct it.

Comment: Please, post what have you tried so far and where have you failed. This service looks pretty basic and there is a lot of information about unit testing angular services in the web.

Comment: I tried to write simple unit test  for above service, I have updated my post with unit test class witch i have write, but it is not working. so i wont to know how to write unit test for above anguler Js service

Comment: Why are you expecting `travelAreaTest()` to return `false`? clearly it returns `'TESTVAL'`.